# Linux firing subshell and stopping whole script

Tags: linux, script, csh

How to make it work?

```
#!/bin/csh
newgrp user_grp2
echo ok
```

"echo ok" is not executed until I write exit in the console. This is sample code.
How to make it work?

I ask in another way: when i run some script with command which has starting a subshell, and i need to not stop executing script after create subshell, then what can i do?
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to understand correctly you jsut want to pass some commands & have them run as `user_grp2` ?

If that is the case you can do the following in your script

```
newgrp user_grp2 <<EOF
echo "This is running as group \$(id -gn)";
touch somefile;
id -gn;
EOF
```